# Can't create new project in Netbeans8.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I just downloaded Netbeans 8.1, I want to start to learn programming in Java. So I downloaded the "All" java bundle and left it to install while I went to school. I suppose it finished installing because when I got back the icon was on my desktop.

When I clicked on New Project, running the program for the FIRST time, I could not create a new project.

[image]

So I run Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't know if I have a problem with my java version or something? Because I've done some research but I can't really use the solutions I got because my problem isn't the same as others I've seen. Can anyone please help me with this?

*EDIT*

Yes! I tried to install the additional plugins that the link recommended, and I got a message: 
[message i get when downloading plugins, like GUI Builder or Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TajoL.png)

It seemed to me from other research I've done that my computer uses the JRE instead of the JDK. So I saw that I have to change that, and I searched my computer for the JDK but I have OpenJDK, which has a folder inside named jre, and Oracle-Java-8, which also has jre inside, but nowhere have I seen a JDK folder... Does this meen I downloaded the wrong type of Java before I downloaded Netbeans?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMissingProjectCategories  seems applicable? Obvious one: make sure there is a JDK and netbeans knows about it

Comment: @Rinzwind I edited my question. Can you help me, please?

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --verbose --config java` Just to be sure.  Also, are you using `umake`?  It's preferred to use `umake` for IDE's.  What exactly did you download and from where?  You should be using `apt` or something like the software center.